# Installing the fcitx5-frontend-qt5 package

Tags: apt, dependencies, qt, fcitx

I am trying to install the fcitx5-frontend-qt5 package so that I can use it on qt applications. Unfortunately, this error comes up every time:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) fcitx5-frontend-qt5:amd64 < none -> 5.0.3-1ubuntu1~focal2 @un puN Ib >
Broken fcitx5-frontend-qt5:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-12-8:amd64 < none @un H >
  Considering libqt5core5a:amd64 4398 as a solution to fcitx5-frontend-qt5:amd64 10000
  Considering libqt5core5a:amd64 4398 as a solution to fcitx5-frontend-qt5:amd64 10000
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fcitx5-frontend-qt5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-8
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As the error message says, it is missing the dependency qtbase-abi-5-12-8. As far as I understand, that package is part of libqt5core5a, which I have installed. The message also says that I have held broken packages, but apt-mark unhold libqt5core5a shows that the package is not on hold.

If anyone knows what is causing this problem, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details; but your paste appears to have both *focal* & *impish* package versions which likely is your issue.. What OS/release are you using?   (If you're using *focal* your should provide the 3rd party source of your packages; which appear to have been taken from *impish*)

Comment: Kubuntu LTS 20.04 (Focal)

Comment: Ok, there are two libqt5core5a packages: libqt5core5a/focal and libqt5core5a/focal-security. There aren't any impish packages